# How to import cURL command to POSTMAN

Tags: curl, postman

I am trying to import a `cURL` command that work in command prompt into POSTMAN

`curl —cert-type p12 —v k -E "file.pem":"1111" --key "file.key" -v "https://blah" -H "Authorization: Bearer blahblahblah" -H "request-id: 123456" -H "someid: 999"`

But i am getting weird message and not sure how to fix it 
`Error while importing Curl: Only the URL can be provided without an option preceding it. All other inputs must be specified via options.`

Does anyone know how to make this import to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

`curl --cert-type p12 -E "file.pem":"1111" --key "file.key" -v  -H "Authorization: Bearer blahblahblah" -H "request-id: 123456" -H "someid: 999" "https://blah"`

I removed the extra `"-v"` at the beginning along with the lurking `"k"` just after it. Also moved the host string to the very end and was able to import the resulting curl command into Postman.

Answer (score 24):

[image]

please change the copy type as above and then import,

Answer (score 0):

Not related to your query but posting for others who have similar issues: You can use the `\` line break for separating options but not long strings. For example:

**Valid**:

```
curl https://google.com \
 --data "some_field=text with no line break" \
 --data "some_other_field=some other text"
```

**Invalid**:

```
curl https://google.com \
 --data "some_field=text with line break"\
"second line of text for field"
```